# Removing redundant using statements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using-statement

Does anyone know of a tool to remove redundant `using` statements from classes, or a whole solution?

I'm using the Refactor! addin which has a "move type to separate file" smart tag, but it takes all the `using` clauses from the original class with it.

Comment: I blame the Chrome spellchecker for my misspelling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PowerCommands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands) for Visual Studio upgrades the default VS.NET 2008 functionality of "Remove Usings" to an entire project or solution.

I use it all the time. It also has a lot of other useful features- check it out.

Best of all it is FREE.

Comment: +1 great tip. I've had PowerCommands installed for quite some time, but I never noticed that before.

Comment: @Joe- I've only recently noticed some of the other things it adds like "extract constant". Probably the most useful though is open containing folder- that's a real obvious feature that Visual Studio should have anyway.

Comment: My favourite PowerCommands feature is Collapse Projects - we work with huge solutions. BTW Open Containing Folder is a feature in VS 2010 :-)

Comment: I've got PowerCommands but didn't notice it there, or Joe's answer

Comment: @Joe- that's useful to know. Collapse projects is a real sanity saver with big solutions.

Answer (score 12):

VisualStudio 2008 does this out of the box.

Simply right click in the code window -> Organise Usings -> Remove Unused Usings.

You can set up a shortcut key to do this, as explained [here](http://www.semdendoncker.com/blog/?p=74).

Answer (score 10):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) does this.